Move email from one account to another account's folder in new outlook
I have two accounts configured in Outlook New Windows app - my_name@org_one.com & my_name@org2.com.
I would like to Move (not copy), an email from the 2nd inbox, to a folder inside the first account. On that email's right-click, the only option is to move to another folder in the same account.
I was able to do this in Outlook Classic.
Have they removed this option in the new version. Is there any hack for this.
Thank you

Looks like they have removed this option.  `Move only shows the directories in the email address.  You probably have to add a rule to auto forward the emails coming from specific addresses.

Agree with cup, it is not supported to move directly from one account to another in New Outlook, as a workaround, you may create related rules to forward these mails you want to move. If this workaround doesn't suit your needs, you might consider switching back to the classic version of Outlook, which still supports this feature.
Meanwhile, i have found a post in feedback collection website, and you could vote for it. Many features of MS current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback. You can also make suggestions on that website and hope Microsoft will notice this in the future.
In addition, there is a similar thread you may feel free to refer to.
Hope it helps.
